# Unhandled exception after specifying a larger size for std::array

Tags: c++, limit, unhandled-exception, stdarray

I have code that looks like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, size_t size>
auto randomly_populate_array(std::mt19937& gen, T lower, T upper) {
    std::array<T, size> arr;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist{ lower, upper };
    for (auto& e : arr) { e = dist(gen); }
    return std::move(arr);
}

int main() {
    try {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen{ rd() };
        constexpr std::size_t arrSize{ 10000 };
        constexpr uint32_t lower = 1, upper = 100;

        std::array<uint32_t, arrSize> A = randomly_populate_array<uint32_t, arrSize>(gen, lower, upper);

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And this seems to run fine, I have other code to print samples from this array, except in my full program I'm generating 4 of them of the same size...

Now when I crank up the value from `10,000` to say `20,000`, `50,000` or `100,000` as I'm trying to make a profiler class for time performance... Visual Studio wants to throw an unhandled exception... The code compiles and builds, but it is throwing a runtime exception...

Here's the message when I change `arrSize` to `20,000`:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000013FB40698 in Simulator.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000001B3000).
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013FB40698 in Simulator.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000001B3000).
```

For the life of me, I can not figure out why... I should be able to create an array with `1,000,000` entries even `100,000,000` on my machine... I have a 64-bit CPU and 8GB of Ram.

And I have already read this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32865482/1757805) and it doesn't answer or resolve my question... I'm not using `dynamic` allocation here. And creating `100,000` 32-bit values should be fine for my system... that should be 400,000 bytes which is what about 50Kb... so any help into resolving this issue is already appreciated.

Comment: `Stack overflow` is pretty explicit about what is wrong.

Comment: So it may not be from just one array, but after trying to create multiple arrays of that size...

Comment: I might have to change my container to `vector` then...

Comment: I can create 4 with 10k elements each, and so far I can create 2 with 20k elements each... but it fails when I created a 3rd with 20k elements...

Comment: Depending on your compiler and/or linker there will be options to increase the stack size, if you have some pressing need to use the stack. But the simple solution is to use a vector. Making a small number of large allocations from the heap is not inefficient